# Sharing information between DAGs in airflow

Tags: airflow

I have one dag that tells another dag what tasks to create in a specific order.

Dag 1 -> a file that has a task order

- This runs every 5 minutes or so to keep this file fresh.

Dag 2 -> runs the task

- this runs daily.

How can I pass this data between the two DAGs using Airflow.

**Solutions and problems**

- The problem with using Airflow Variables is that I cannot set them at runtime.
- The problem with using Xcoms is that they can only be run during the task stage and once the tasks are created in Dag 2, they're set and cannot be changed correct?
- The problem with pushing the file to s3 is that the airflow instance doesn't have permission to pull from s3 due to security reasons decided by a team that I have no control over.

So what can I do? What are some choices I have?

Comment: What do you mean by "The problem with using Airflow Variables is that I cannot set them at runtime."? I was thinking that DAG1 executing a `Variable.set(...)` command satisfies your use case at first glance but there may be a little more to the story.

Comment: Can't you just discover the order as the first step of Dag-2?

Comment: Ah I didn't realize `Variable.set` was a thing. It wasn't in the docs... Can I call this outside of tasks? Can I call this in setup code for tasks?

Answer (score 1):

What is the file format of the output from the 1st DAG? I would recommend the following workflow

Dag 1 -> Update the tasks order and store it in a yaml or json file inside the airflow environment.

Dag 2 -> Read the file to create the required tasks and run them daily.

You need to understand that airflow is constantly reading your dag files to have the latest configuration, so no extra step would be required.

Comment: How do I do step 1? Where can I store it? and how?

Comment: This has to be done with a PythonOperator or CustomOperator. Using the [PyYaml](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) library you can manipulate Yaml files from Python. You can store a file in the same folder where your DAG scripts are, or in any other folder you can setup in the same environment where Airflow is running. The only requirement is to keep this file locally, so the reading can be as fast as possible.

Comment: I assume you already have an operator that defines the tasks order. If so, try extending the work of this operator to do this task.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue in the past and it largely depends on your setup.

If you are running Airflow on Kubernetes this might work.

1. You create a PV(Persistent Volume) and PVC
2. You start your application with a KubernetesOperator and mount the PVC to it.
3. You store the result on the PVC.
4. You mount the PVC to the other pod.